# difference between jstats and jmx in visualvm

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm, jstatd

I am using visualvm to monitor my production server which has both jmx and jstatd.

I tried both protocol in visual vm but seems very identical, is there any difference using jmx or jstatd to monitor a server (in term of monitoring possibility, bandwith usage, cpu usage , etc...) ?

Should I prefer one solution over another ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

JMX does not allow detailed 'jstat' monitoring details as required by several plugins in 'VisualVM' like the 'VisualGC' plugin.

'jstatd' is the daemon that allows a 'jstat' connection to be established.